# How can I prove binomial identities using the Binomial Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I've got a good handle on how to prove binomial identities using a committee argument, but how would I go about trying to use the Binomial Theorem to prove them?

For example, $\dbinom{2n}2=2\dbinom   n2+n^2$

I've got a pretty good handle on proving this identity using a committee argument where I form a committee of size 2 from an initial group size of 2n, and then I break up this committee into two separate groups.

My question is, how can I use the Binomial Theorem to prove this identity?

Comment: The binomial theorem isn’t really relevant to that identity: a combinatorial argument of the kind that you suggest works fine, and so does a simple algebraic verification.

Comment: I suppose the question worth asking is why would you want to use an algebraic approach tied to the binomial theorem as opposed to the combinatorial argument approach (e.g. committee arguments)? Granted it might just be me, but I usually find the latter a lot easier to grasp.

Comment: It is possible by expanding $(1+x)^{2n} = (1+x)^n(1+x)^n$ and considering the coefficient of $x^2$, which becomes proving a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) where $m = n$ and $r = 2$. Or use the formula of binomial coefficients:

$$\binom k2 = \frac{k!}{2!(k-2)!} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$